# React Navigation - 1 pixel of tab color is white

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, helper

How do I solve this problem where there is 1 pixel of white in the tab bar (as demonstrated in the photo)?

I'm using React Navigation.

[image]

Comment: share your tab bar code and styles please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding borderTopWidth:0 to style in tabBarOptions will fix this issue.

```html
 <Tab.Navigator
 ......
 tabBarOptions={{
         ...
          style: {
            ...
            borderTopWidth: 0,
          },
}}
/>
```